# How can I change the information stored in firmware of a Zebra QL320 plus?

Tags: zebra-printers, firmware

I work for a company that resells a lot of old technology and we just got bunch of QL320 pluses. The problem is before they can be resold I need to remove any trace of the previous owner. However it looks like zebra might have provided the vendor with custom firmware. I can change the text that displays easily enough but I can't remove the name that displays during boot up. After looking at the files on the QLs, specifically a file called CUSTOM.WML I think I've found the location of the information I need to change.

```xml
    <do type="accept" label="Retail company">
    <setvar name="vnd.zo.ip.remote_port" value="100"/>
    <setvar name="vnd.zo.appl.ps.division" value="R"/>
     <refresh/>
    </do>
         </br>
```

It looks like I'm looking for the location of `vnd.zo.appl.ps.division`. Does anyone by chance know how I can view this file or make changes to it?

Update: after I doing some more research I think I just solved my own problem. WML is completely new to me so here goes nothing.